# Text Field Stores to Array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently developing a web app which allows to put their list of skills (I'm not sure what it called). Here is the example:

[image: example]

The point is, there will be a text field and then when the user types "ruby on rails" for example and hit enter the "ruby on rails" will be saved and the user can type another skill they have for example, "marketing" and then when the user hit enter, the user can type another skill and so on.

Comment: Those tags look familiar ... It's almost like some other website inspired you .. But which site ...?

Comment: you can use rails Serialization, to store array http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: If you mean the UI part, try [bootstrap-tagsinput](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker it's stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Aetherus yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! But how to implement in in Rails?

Comment: Tagging is not a trivial thing if you wanna apply searching on it. If you just wanna store and display the tags, then just concatenate them and store them in a varchar column. If you wanna apply searching with `=`, then you probably need a many-to-many association. If you wanna apply some crazy stuff like full-text search, then relational database is just not your thing. You have to use something like `ElasticSearch`.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to know. There are many aspects in implementing such a system. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option for You is `select2`. Check out docs and examples here: [select2](http://select2.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem 'bootstrap-tagsinput-rails' to implement tags input using bootstrap theme. Look at [here for documentation.](https://github.com/luciuschoi/bootstrap-tagsinput-rails)